# How to connect to Amazon Redshift or other DB's in Apache Spark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to connect to Amazon Redshift via Spark, so I can join data we have on S3 with data on our RS cluster. I found some very spartan documentation here for the capability of connecting to JDBC:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

The load command seems fairly straightforward (although I don't know how I would enter AWS credentials here, maybe in the options?).

```
df = sqlContext.load(source="jdbc", url="jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", dbtable="schema.tablename")
```

And I'm not entirely sure how to deal with the SPARK_CLASSPATH variable. I'm running Spark locally for now through an iPython notebook (as part of the Spark distribution). Where do I define that so that Spark loads it?

Anyway, for now, when I try running these commands, I get a bunch of undecipherable errors, so I'm kind of stuck for now. Any help or pointers to detailed tutorials are appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Although this seems to be a very old post, anyone who is still looking for answer, below steps worked for me!

Start the shell including the jar.

```
bin/pyspark --driver-class-path /path_to_postgresql-42.1.4.jar --jars /path_to_postgresql-42.1.4.jar
```

Create a df by giving appropriate details:

```
myDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://host:port/db_name") \
    .option("dbtable", "table_name") \
    .option("user", "user_name") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .load()
```

**Spark Version: 2.2**

Comment: I've tried the above solution, but fails with driver not found. Is there a special postgresql driver? i am using 42.2.5.

Answer (score 6):

It turns out you only need a username/pwd to access Redshift in Spark, and it is done as follows (using the Python API):

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.load(source="jdbc", 
                     url="jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbserver?user=yourusername&password=secret", 
                     dbtable="schema.table"
)
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I don’t use the Scala api but I assume it’s not that different.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Spark 1.4.0 or newer, check out [`spark-redshift`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift), a library which supports loading data from Redshift into Spark SQL DataFrames and saving DataFrames back to Redshift. If you're querying large volumes of data, this approach should perform better than JDBC because it will be able to unload and query the data in parallel.

If you still want to use JDBC, check out the new [built-in JDBC data source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) in Spark 1.4+.

Disclosure: I'm one of the authors of `spark-redshift`.

Comment: @JoseRosen May I know if spark-redshift supports updating a few rows? What is the best way to update only a few rows in redshift?

Comment: @santhosh: `spark-redshift` does not currently support upserts; see https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/195

Comment: Note: [`spark-redshift`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) is no longer maintained publicly.  Databricks has chosen to make it exclusively private and not publish any further updates outside of their cluster images.  See the answer from @Sumit for a current method using the Postgres driver.

Answer (score 2):

You first need to download Postgres JDBC driver. You can find it here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/

You can either define your environment variable SPARK_CLASSPATH in `.bashrc`, conf/spark-env.sh or similar file or specify it in the script before you run your IPython notebook.

You can also define it in your conf/spark-defaults.conf in the following way:

```
spark.driver.extraClassPath  /path/to/file/postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar
```

Make sure it is reflected in the Environment tab of your Spark WebUI.

You will also need to set appropriate AWS credentials in the following way:

```
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "***")
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "***")
```

Comment: Thanks! I am able to see the postgres class in the Environment tab now, so that seems to have worked. However I am getting the following error after trying to run the AWS seetings: "AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'hadoopConfiguration'" --- Is there a newer setting perhaps?

Comment: So, upon doing some research, I found that hadoopConfiguration is only available in the Scala API. I am using Python. Any workaround?

Comment: It is generally good idea to keep SparkContext immutable, so pass all your configuration when you create SparkContext.
In Ipython notebooks, however, you may want to change it because sc has been created for you. In this case you can access the java methods of sc through `sc._jsc`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
The simplest way to make a jdbc connection to Redshift using python is as follows:

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

jdbc_url = "jdbc:redshift://xxx.xxx.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/xxx"
jdbc_user = "xxx"
jdbc_password = "xxx"
jdbc_driver = "com.databricks.spark.redshift"

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("yarn") \
.config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

# Read data from a query
df = spark.read \
    .format(jdbc_driver) \
    .option("url", jdbc_url + "?user="+ jdbc_user +"&password="+ jdbc_password) \
    .option("query", "your query") \
    .load()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for in Scala in AWS Glue with Spark 2.4:

```
val spark: SparkContext = new SparkContext()
val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)
Job.init(args("JOB_NAME"), glueContext, args.asJava)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(spark)
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
  Map("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://HOST:PORT/DBNAME?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD",
  "dbtable" -> "(SELECT a.row_name FROM schema_name.table_name a) as from_redshift")).load()

// back to DynamicFrame
val datasource0 = DynamicFrame(jdbcDF, glueContext)
```

Works with any SQL query.