# Sending data from my spark code to redshift

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I have a Spark code programmed in Scala. My code reads an xml and extracts all the info in it. The goal is to store the info from the XML into Redshift tables.

Is it possible to send the data directly from my Scala Spark code to Redshift without using S3?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spark SQL you can read your XML data into DataFrame using [spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) and then writing it into Redshift tables using [spark-redshift](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) .
You can also take a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395743/how-to-connect-to-amazon-redshift-or-other-dbs-in-apache-spark) .

Answer (score 0):

You can do row level insert using pre-prepared SQL statements into your Python/ Java code, but it will be extremely inefficient if you are going to insert more than few records.