# Alternatives to the connector spark-redshift

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, databricks

I would like to know it there is any other alternative to the spark-redshift connector. It seems it is not longer maintained since this library is automatically included in the Databricks cluster images for Spark 2.1.0-db2 and later versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no current alternative with equivalent functionality - the closest available is through usage of the Postgres JDBC driver.  [See this thread for information on usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31395743/2738164).  Unfortunately, great features such as full query pushdown are exclusive to the closed-source Databricks implementation right now.