# Execute queries on redshift using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, amazon-connect

Can any one of you suggest the method of executing queries on redshift tables using pyspark?

Comment: This might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395743/how-to-connect-to-amazon-redshift-or-other-dbs-in-apache-spark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to Amazon Redshift or other DB's in Apache Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395743/how-to-connect-to-amazon-redshift-or-other-dbs-in-apache-spark)

Answer (score 0):

Using pyspark data-frames option is one option to read/write to Redshift tables. And executing queries with dataframe's help is restricted to using `preactions`/`postactions` method.
If you need to execute multiple queries, one way is to use `psycopg2` module.
First, you need to install psycopg2 module on your server:
`sudo python -m pip install psycopg2`
Then open the pyspark shell and execute the following:

```
import psycopg2

conn={'db_name': {'hostname':'redshift_host_url','database':'database_on_redshift','username':'redshift_username','password':'p', 'port':your_port} }

db='db_name'

hostname, username, password, database, portnumber = conn[db]['hostname'], conn[db]['username'], conn[db]['password'], conn[db]['database'], conn[db]['port']

con = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, port=portnumber, user=username, password=password, dbname=database)

query="insert into sample_table select * from table1"
cur = con.cursor()
rs = cur.execute(query)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

You can also refer: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html